# Any way to amend/edit own suggested edits

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits

I recently went through a number of unanswered questions and while reading them realized that the flow of the question could be improved by editing the post, which I then did for some of them.

At one point I found myself in the situation that right after hitting the 'Save Edits' button I found another point that I missed in my edit and that I would have liked to fix also. 
Given that accepted edits are a way to get credits, I did not want to edit the post again as it seemed like a cheesy way to get double credit. I would have liked to amend my own edit, but didn't find any way to do that.

Is there any functionality that I missed that may have allowed me to further improve my suggestions for improvement without appearing as simply fishing for reputation?

If not: what would be a good way to handle a situation like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any way to amend an edit suggestion once it's been approved or rejected. However, you can make adjustments to a suggestion while it's still under review. The main problem will be that suggestions don't remain in review for very long.

While you state that you don't want to profit by making a further edit you should have seen the first time round, that's all you can do.

However, I can't imagine that good things will happen if it's spotted that you keep making edits to the same post.

Comment: @ChrisF "The main problem will be that suggestions don't remain in review for very long." That was indeed the case here, it took only a few seconds to be approved so there was nothing I could do.

Comment: "However, I can't imagine that good things will happen if it's spotted that you keep making edits to the same post." I couldn't agree more, it seemed inherently wrong to me do this in the first place. Now that I know that I also cannot fix this a posteriori, I simply need to be even more vigilant before submitting edits :/

Comment: @Erik: Just get to 2k fast, then you don't need to propose edits any more...